# Empty dict passed through recursive function calls is being seen as `NoneType`

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, null

I have a recursive function that is being used by a bot to play a game of Connect Four To give you a basic idea of what is happening in the function - it uses Monte Carlo search to select the next move that will statistically have the best win:lose ratio out of all possible moves

However, none of this information is necessary for my problem. My recursive function takes as one of its parameters an empty dictionary `{}` the first time it is called. This dictionary is  passed into each recursive call until a point where the end of the game is reached. At this point, the dictionary is modified and returned, and so this dictionary is passed through all recursive calls and eventually returned all the way back up to the initial call to the function. Each key to the dictionary is an instance of my class `Cell`, and each value is a list of length 2 of integers.

As I intiially call the recursive function with an empty dict, at the first point where the end of the game is reached, I need to add the first `Cell` - `[int, int]` key-value pair to the dict, and in doing so, I have an if statement to check if the key already exists in the dictionary.

At this point I am gettting the error:

```
in __MonteCarloSearch
    if startingCell in winRatios:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Here is my code and I have commented the line that is causing the error:

```
def getMove(self, prompt, grid):
    winRatios = self.__MonteCarloSearch(grid, True, {}, None)
    bestCell = [None, None]
    for cell, ratio in winRatios.items():
        if ratio[0] / ratio[1] > bestCell[1]:
            bestCell = Cell

    return cell.colLabel

def __MonteCarloSearch(self, grid, myMove, winRatios, startingCell):   # COUNT NUM SEQUENCE SIMULATED
    for cell in grid:
        if startingCell is None:
            startingCell = cell
        cellBelow = None
        if cell.row > 0:
            cellBelow = grid.getCellFromLabel(cell.colLabel + rowLabels[cell.row - 1])
        if (cell.value == empty or cell.value == blocked) and (cell.row == 0 or cellBelow.value != empty):
            testGrid = deepcopy(grid)
            if myMove:
                testGrid.placeChip(cell.colLabel, self.chip)
            else:
                testGrid.placeChip(cell.colLabel, chips[(chips.index(self.chip) + 1) % len(chips)])
            gameWon, gridFull = testGrid.gameOver()
            if gameWon and myMove:
                if startingCell in winRatios:   # ERROR PRODUCED HERE
                    winRatios[startingCell] = [winRatios[startingCell][0] + 1, winRatios[startingCell][1] + 1]
                else:
                    winRatios[startingCell] = [1, 1]
                return winRatios
            if (gameWon and not myMove) or gridFull:
                if startingCell in winRatios:   # ERROR PRODUCED HERE
                    winRatios[startingCell] = [winRatios[startingCell][0], winRatios[startingCell][1] + 1]
                else:
                    winRatios[startingCell] = [0, 1]
                return winRatios
            winRatios = self.__MonteCarloSearch(testGrid, not myMove, winRatios, startingCell)
```

Also, I have changed the line to `if winRatios and startingCell in winRatios`, but then receive the similar error:

```
in __MonteCarloSearch
    winRatios[startingCell] = [0, 1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `winRatios` at the end of your function. There are code paths which don't return the `winRatios` value back from the recursive call, which ends up returning an implicit None.

For example, this will happen when

`if (cell.value == empty or cell.value == blocked) and (cell.row == 0 or cellBelow.value != empty):`

does not evaluate to True for any of the cells in the for loop.

Comment: Ah yes I see, simply adding `return winRatios` to the very last line fo the function solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If this worked for you, could you please mark the answer as "accepted"? :)

Comment: Yes it says I have to wait another 5 minutes, will do it then!